# Cartesian product of transitive group actions, stabilizer groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions

Consider a finite group $G$ and subgroups $\{H_i\}_{i=0,\ldots,n-1}$ (defined up to conjugacy) such that $G$ acts transitively on each $G/H_i$ [edit: in the canonical way]. Consider the induced action of $G$ on the cartesian product $\prod_{0\leq i<n} G/H_i$. This action is not necessarily transitive.

**Question**: Is there a nice description of the orbits of this action and their (conjugacy classes of) stabilizers?

If I remember correctly, for the cartesian product of two transitive actions, the orbits are in one-to-one correspondence with double cosets $H_0\backslash G/H_1$. Not sure how to get the stabilizers though.

Comment: You wrote *... such that $G$ acts transitively on each $G/H_i$...*, but you did not specify which transitive action. Did you intend it to be stated for any old transitive action of $G$ on $G/H_i$? Or did you instead intend it to be the "standard" transitive action $g \cdot (g'H_i) = (gg') H_i$?

Comment: Yes, the standard one. Sorry, thought that was clear from the context.

Comment: Just found out about the Burnside ring, which allows for computing the decomposition of the cartesian-product action into orbits, specified by their conjugacy classes of subgroups, via tables of marks. Is there an elegant way to also compute a representative of each orbit?